# What does "WHERE x = ?" mean in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

This code is written in C# and it is calling database to get the data from it. But I don't understand what does "WHERE b.CompRec = ?" mean

```
    public string GetFileNameAndTitle(int compRec)
    {
        string fileNameAndTitle = "";
        string sql = "SELECT a.FileName, a.Title FROM (Files a INNER JOIN Components b ON a.RecNo=b.FileRec) WHERE b.CompRec = ?";
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn))
        {               
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompRec", compRec);
            OpenConnection();    }
```

Comment: The `?` gets substituted with an actual value later on.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically a placeholder where you will put data later. This lets you split up your SQL statement from the data used in the query. This is the syntax of parameterized statements.

Answer (score 10):

It is a parameterized statement.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompRec", compRec);
```

That line sets the actual value when the query is executed at the server. This prevents SQL Injection and is the 100% right approach!

Comment: The 100% right can be to create a SP and just call the SP instead off using dynamic SQL (that helps the engine) and to type the parameters to tell the DB what he is geting.

Comment: @jean, that's quite arguable. The statement's execution plan would get cached the first time through, and subsequent calls would use the same plan because it's parameterized.

Comment: @jean `AddWithValue` infers the type. It's only if this inferrence is wrong or could be more precise that you'd benefit from explicitly typing them via SP or something else.

Comment: Great answer Michael, +1.